# postgresql server failed to start after system upgrade

Tags: postgresql, debian

I upgrade debian server then I got this error:

```
[....] Starting PostgreSQL 9.1 database server: main[....] The PostgreSQL server
[FAILed to start. Please check the log output. ... failed!
 failed!
```

But the log file is empty.

Can anyone help me to start PostgreSQL?

Comment: Can you state your log output?

Comment: Do all the data files have the correct permissions and ownership? Does the logfile belong to user/group postgres?

Comment: Have a look at: http://serverfault.com/questions/587239/postgres-server-fails-to-start-produces-no-log-how-to-to-troubleshoot

Comment: So what's in the log output?

Comment: In the postgresql forum some similar problem was solved: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/515DE012.9010705@especific.be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem I changed the owner of the log file to `postgres`:

```
chown postgres:posgres logfile_path
```